# apa-biblatex citation of youtube video returns (typedirector) after author

Tags: biblatex, apa-style

I'm doing my thesis in LaTeX. Recently I used a youtube video for a reference. After compiling, it returned the following:

[image]

As far as I'm concern, **(typedirector)** shouldn't appear.

My preamble is:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel} % pone el idioma en español

\setcounter{tocdepth}{3} % pone en TOC hasta la subsubsección
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3} % enumera hasta la subsubsección

\usepackage{lipsum} % dummy text
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{geometry} % margenes del documento
\geometry{letterpaper, top = {2,5cm}, bottom = {2,5cm}, inner = {2,5cm},
outer = {2,5cm}, head = {1,1cm}, foot = {1,1cm}, bindingoffset = {1,0cm}}
% Si se va a usar dos paginas por hoja, agregar la opción twoside

\usepackage{helvet} % Arial
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault} % Arial

\usepackage{titlesec} % cambiar modo de ver capitulos y secciones
\titleformat{\chapter}[display] 
{\large\bfseries\centering}{\MakeUppercase\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{1em}{\MakeUppercase}{} % Cambios en Capitulo

\titleformat{\section}{\large\bfseries}{\thesection.}{1em}{\MakeUppercase}

\titleformat{\subsection}{\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesubsection.}{1em}{\MakeUppercase} % Cambios en SubSección

\titleformat{\subsubsection}{\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesubsubsection.}{1em}{\MakeUppercase} % Cambios en SubSubSección

\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-2.5em}{3em} % Cambia el espaciamiento del capitulo de 50pt a lo pedido

\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{3em}{2em} % Cambia el espaciamiento de la sección a 3 espacios en blanco antes y 2 despues.

\usepackage{enumitem}
%\setlist[enumerate]{label=\thesection.\arabic*., leftmargin=*}

%\renewcommand*{\theenumi}{\thechapter.\arabic{enumi}} % numero de capitulo en listas
%\renewcommand*{\theenumii}{\theenumi.\arabic{enumi}} % añade lo anterior a sublistas

\usepackage{titletoc}
 \titlecontents{chapter}[0em]
    {\vspace{0em}}
    {\normalfont\normalsize\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel.]{2em}\uppercase}
    {\hspace*{-2em}\uppercase}
    {\titlerule*[.75em]{.}\contentspage}
    
\titlecontents{section}[2em]
    {\vspace{0em}}
    {\normalfont\normalsize\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel.]{2em}\uppercase}
    {\hspace*{-2em}\uppercase}
    {\titlerule*[.75em]{.}\contentspage}
    
\titlecontents{subsection}[5em]
    {\vspace{0em}}
    {\normalfont\normalsize\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel.]{2.9em}\uppercase}
    {\hspace*{-2em}\uppercase}
    {\titlerule*[.75em]{.}\contentspage}
    
\titlecontents{subsubsection}[9em]
    {\vspace{0em}}
    {\normalfont\normalsize\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel.]{3.8em}\uppercase}
    {\hspace*{-2em}\uppercase}
    {\titlerule*[.75em]{.}\contentspage}
    

\usepackage{setspace}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5} % interlineado de 1.5

\usepackage[skip=6pt, indent=1cm, tocskip]{parskip} % configurar espacio entre parrafos y sangría izquierda. tocskip genera el salto entre parrafos en el indice

% paquetes necesarios para citar
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa, backend=biber, sortcites, url=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliografia.bib}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\chapter}{\thispagestyle{plain}}{\thispagestyle{fancy}}{}{} % necesario para poner encabezado en paginas de capítulos

% paquete para encabezado y pie de pagina 
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

\fancypagestyle{mystyle}{
    \fancyfoot{}
    \renewcommand{\thepage}{\ifnum\value{page}<10 0\fi\arabic{page}}
}

\pagestyle{mystyle} % Aplicar el estilo de numeración de página personalizado

\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption} %% Formato de pies de foto

\usepackage[]{hyperref}

% - - - - - COMANDOS - - - - -
\newenvironment{itemizecita}{%
    \begin{itemize}
        \setlength{\leftskip}{1.27cm}
    }{%
    \end{itemize}
}

\long\def\citalarga#1{%
    \medskip
    \begingroup
    \parindent 0pt
    \leftskip=1.27cm
    #1
    \par
    \endgroup
    \medskip
}

\long\def\citalargacontinuacion#1{\medskip 
    \begingroup
    \parindent 1.27cm
    \leftskip=1.27cm
    #1 \par \medskip
    \endgroup
}

\long\def\resej#1{\medskip 
    \begingroup
    \parindent 0pt
    \leftskip=1.5em
    #1 \par \medskip
    \endgroup
}
% - - - - -  PORTADA - - - - -  

\title{\textbf{\MakeUppercase{text}}}
\author{text}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyhead[L]{}
\fancyhead[R]{}
\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}
\fancyheadoffset[lh]{2cm}

%% - - - - -  RESUMEN EJECUTIVO - - - - -  
%
\include{1-resumen-ejecutivo.tex} % works
%

\tableofcontents
% - - - - -  INTRODUCCIÓN - - - - -  

\clearpage % para que el siguiente comando empiece en una página nueva
\pagenumbering{arabic} % numeración en números arábigos
\include{2-introduccion.tex} % works

% - - - - -  CAPÍTULO 1  - - - - -  

\include{3-capitulo-1.tex} % works

% - - - - -  CAPÍTULO 2 - - - - -  

\include{4-capitulo-2.tex} % doesn't work

% - - - - -  CAPÍTULO 3  - - - - -  

\include{5-capitulo-3.tex}% doesn't work

% - - - - -  BIBLIOGRAFÍA - - - - -  

\printbibliography


\end{document}
```

The citation inside my .bib file is:

```
@video{solarsolutionSolarPanelsExplained2021,
  entrysubtype = {video},
  title = {Solar {{Panels Explained}}: {{Mono}} // {{Poly PV Crystalline}} // {{PERC}} // {{Thin Film Modules}}},
  shorttitle = {Solar {{Panels Explained}}},
  editor = {{Solar Solution}},
  editortype = {director},
  date = {2021-09-11},
  url = {https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ue3udnwuA5g},
  abstract = {Course trailer and Coupon Code:~~~•~Off-Grid~Energy~C...~~ === Energy Engineer Jesse Gorter explains in this video how solar panels work, which materials they are made of, and what makes one panel better than the other. ✅  Content: 02:00 Photo Voltaics 04:37 Material Options 05:24 Solar Panel Efficiency 08:12 From PV Cell to Module 09:01 PV Busbars and Fingers 11:25 Solar Panel Layers 14:02 Bypass Diodes 16:14 MC4 Connectors ✅  YouTube Channel ~~~/~solarsolution~~ ✅  Playlists Wiring ~~~•~Wiring~~ Costs ~~~•~Cost~-~Off~grid~~ Charging ~~~•~Charging~~ Batteries ~~~•~Batteries~~ Solar Panels ~~~•~Solar~Panels~~ ✅  Online Video Course Learn more through the Online Video Courses: https://courses.solarsolution.co ✅  Facebook https://web.facebook.com/solarsolutio... ✅  LinkedIn https://www.linkedin.com/company/sola... ✅  Website https://www.solarsolution.co/contact DISCLAIMER: The content of this video is for information purposes only. If you choose to use any information provided through this video, you do so at your own risk. Viewing and/or listening to this video does not form a professional relationship of any kind. All rights reserved.  COPYRIGHT Solar Solution. \#Solar Panel \#PV Module \# PV Module \#Photovoltaic module}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your question is a duplicate of [Biblatex APA style does not support editor types?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/466884/biblatex-apa-style-does-not-support-editor-types)

You have to define `typedirector` string (in Spanish, since you're using that language), adding this code:

```
\NewBibliographyString{director}
\NewBibliographyString{directors}
\NewBibliographyString{bydirector}
\NewBibliographyString{cbydirector}
\NewBibliographyString{typedirector}
\NewBibliographyString{typedirectors}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{spanish}{%
  director      = {director},
  directors     = {directores},
  typedirector  = {director},
  typedirectors = {directores},
  bydirector    = {dirigido por},
  cbydirector   = {dir\adddot},
}
```

Here is the complete example (next time, try to make your MWE *minimal*):

```
\begin{filecontents}{bibliografia.bib}
@video{solarsolutionSolarPanelsExplained2021,
  entrysubtype = {video},
  title = {Solar {{Panels Explained}}: {{Mono}} // {{Poly PV Crystalline}} // {{PERC}} // {{Thin Film Modules}}},
  shorttitle = {Solar {{Panels Explained}}},
  editor = {{Solar Solution}},
  editortype = {director},
  date = {2021-09-11},
  url = {https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ue3udnwuA5g},
  abstract = {Course trailer and Coupon Code:~~~•~Off-Grid~Energy~C...~~ === Energy Engineer Jesse Gorter explains in this video how solar panels work, which materials they are made of, and what makes one panel better than the other. ✅  Content: 02:00 Photo Voltaics 04:37 Material Options 05:24 Solar Panel Efficiency 08:12 From PV Cell to Module 09:01 PV Busbars and Fingers 11:25 Solar Panel Layers 14:02 Bypass Diodes 16:14 MC4 Connectors ✅  YouTube Channel ~~~/~solarsolution~~ ✅  Playlists Wiring ~~~•~Wiring~~ Costs ~~~•~Cost~-~Off~grid~~ Charging ~~~•~Charging~~ Batteries ~~~•~Batteries~~ Solar Panels ~~~•~Solar~Panels~~ ✅  Online Video Course Learn more through the Online Video Courses: https://courses.solarsolution.co ✅  Facebook https://web.facebook.com/solarsolutio... ✅  LinkedIn https://www.linkedin.com/company/sola... ✅  Website https://www.solarsolution.co/contact DISCLAIMER: The content of this video is for information purposes only. If you choose to use any information provided through this video, you do so at your own risk. Viewing and/or listening to this video does not form a professional relationship of any kind. All rights reserved.  COPYRIGHT Solar Solution. \#Solar Panel \#PV Module \# PV Module \#Photovoltaic module}
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[12pt]{report}

%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}<--- no more needed
\usepackage[spanish]{babel} % pone el idioma en español

\setcounter{tocdepth}{3} % pone en TOC hasta la subsubsección
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3} % enumera hasta la subsubsección

\usepackage{lipsum} % dummy text
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{geometry} % margenes del documento
\geometry{letterpaper, top = {2,5cm}, bottom = {2,5cm}, inner = {2,5cm},
outer = {2,5cm}, head = {1,1cm}, foot = {1,1cm}, bindingoffset = {1,0cm}}
% Si se va a usar dos paginas por hoja, agregar la opción twoside

\usepackage{helvet} % Arial
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault} % Arial

\usepackage{titlesec} % cambiar modo de ver capitulos y secciones
\titleformat{\chapter}[display] 
{\large\bfseries\centering}{\MakeUppercase\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{1em}{\MakeUppercase}{} % Cambios en Capitulo

\titleformat{\section}{\large\bfseries}{\thesection.}{1em}{\MakeUppercase}

\titleformat{\subsection}{\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesubsection.}{1em}{\MakeUppercase} % Cambios en SubSección

\titleformat{\subsubsection}{\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesubsubsection.}{1em}{\MakeUppercase} % Cambios en SubSubSección

\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-2.5em}{3em} % Cambia el espaciamiento del capitulo de 50pt a lo pedido

\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{3em}{2em} % Cambia el espaciamiento de la sección a 3 espacios en blanco antes y 2 despues.

\usepackage{enumitem}
%\setlist[enumerate]{label=\thesection.\arabic*., leftmargin=*}

%\renewcommand*{\theenumi}{\thechapter.\arabic{enumi}} % numero de capitulo en listas
%\renewcommand*{\theenumii}{\theenumi.\arabic{enumi}} % añade lo anterior a sublistas

\usepackage{titletoc}
 \titlecontents{chapter}[0em]
    {\vspace{0em}}
    {\normalfont\normalsize\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel.]{2em}\uppercase}
    {\hspace*{-2em}\uppercase}
    {\titlerule*[.75em]{.}\contentspage}
    
\titlecontents{section}[2em]
    {\vspace{0em}}
    {\normalfont\normalsize\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel.]{2em}\uppercase}
    {\hspace*{-2em}\uppercase}
    {\titlerule*[.75em]{.}\contentspage}
    
\titlecontents{subsection}[5em]
    {\vspace{0em}}
    {\normalfont\normalsize\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel.]{2.9em}\uppercase}
    {\hspace*{-2em}\uppercase}
    {\titlerule*[.75em]{.}\contentspage}
    
\titlecontents{subsubsection}[9em]
    {\vspace{0em}}
    {\normalfont\normalsize\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel.]{3.8em}\uppercase}
    {\hspace*{-2em}\uppercase}
    {\titlerule*[.75em]{.}\contentspage}
    

\usepackage{setspace}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5} % interlineado de 1.5

\usepackage[skip=6pt, indent=1cm, tocskip]{parskip} % configurar espacio entre parrafos y sangría izquierda. tocskip genera el salto entre parrafos en el indice

% paquetes necesarios para citar
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa, sortcites]{biblatex}% backend=biber and url=true are defaults, no need to add them
\NewBibliographyString{director}
\NewBibliographyString{directors}
\NewBibliographyString{bydirector}
\NewBibliographyString{cbydirector}
\NewBibliographyString{typedirector}
\NewBibliographyString{typedirectors}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{spanish}{%
  director      = {director},
  directors     = {directores},
  typedirector  = {director},
  typedirectors = {directores},
  bydirector    = {dirigido por},
  cbydirector   = {dir\adddot},
}

\addbibresource{bibliografia.bib}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\chapter}{\thispagestyle{plain}}{\thispagestyle{fancy}}{}{} % necesario para poner encabezado en paginas de capítulos

% paquete para encabezado y pie de pagina 
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

\fancypagestyle{mystyle}{
    \fancyfoot{}
    \renewcommand{\thepage}{\ifnum\value{page}<10 0\fi\arabic{page}}
}

\pagestyle{mystyle} % Aplicar el estilo de numeración de página personalizado

\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption} %% Formato de pies de foto

\usepackage[]{hyperref}

% - - - - - COMANDOS - - - - -
\newenvironment{itemizecita}{%
    \begin{itemize}
        \setlength{\leftskip}{1.27cm}
    }{%
    \end{itemize}
}

\long\def\citalarga#1{%
    \medskip
    \begingroup
    \parindent 0pt
    \leftskip=1.27cm
    #1
    \par
    \endgroup
    \medskip
}

\long\def\citalargacontinuacion#1{\medskip 
    \begingroup
    \parindent 1.27cm
    \leftskip=1.27cm
    #1 \par \medskip
    \endgroup
}

\long\def\resej#1{\medskip 
    \begingroup
    \parindent 0pt
    \leftskip=1.5em
    #1 \par \medskip
    \endgroup
}
% - - - - -  PORTADA - - - - -  

\title{\textbf{\MakeUppercase{text}}}
\author{text}
\date{}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Off-topic: are you sure to have "BIBLIOGRAFÍA" on both top sides of your page?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I would give it a try, and yes, I should make my MWE more minimal. Sorry for the complex (and probably hard to read) preamble. About the "BIBLIOGRAFÍA" thing, I removed some content of the headers, so it probably autofilled it with chapter name.

Comment: This solves my issue! Thanks for your time! Tried using the other question solutions, but it returner (Dir.) instead of (Director), so your answer is more accurate for a Spanish citation.

Comment: @JJP You're welcome! Thank you for accepting my answer!